# Mots synonymes : unicité ou ressemblance

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Il y a des langues où  chaque mot est unique dans son sens.
Je me demande, alors, pour la langue française est-ce que c'est le cas?

C'est à dire, lorsqu'on parle de mots synonymes: Est-ce que ces sont des mots

- Dont les sens sont proches.

Ou

- Qui peuvent avoir exactement le même sens.

Merci

Comment: Les deux ! Un synonyme est un mot [qui a le même sens ou un sens voisin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/synonyme).

Comment: Par curiosité, quelle langue a des synonymes *exacts* ? Si l'on considère le sens d'un mot comme *la manière dont est donnée la référence*, deux mots différents **ne peuvent pas** avoir le même sens. Deux synonymes sont, au mieux, *presque* équivalents, quelle que soit la langue me semble-t-il.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Au sens strict du terme, les synonymes ont la même signification. "Cyan" n'est pas un synonyme de "bleu" ou de "turquoise". En revanche, il existe des synonymes qui ont la même signification matérielle mais que l'usage culturel (littérature ou conversation usuelle) a rendu chargés d'une nuance : un "lâche" est la version courante de "couard" : ils ont la même signification mais n'ont ni le même registre ni le même emploi.

Comment: Ce que tu appelles ici *la même signification matérielle*, c'est la *référence*. Et la *nuance* dont tu parles, c'est bel et bien le *sens* du mot ! Comme tu le dis très bien au départ, *cyan* et *turquoise* ne sont pas synonymes. Ils n'ont même pas la même référence, donc on ne peut pas réellement comparer leur sens. *livre* et *bouquin* ont la même référence, mais ont un sens différent, donc des connotations et un usage différent : ce sont des synonymes.

Comment: Et désolé de cette envolée technique, ce n'était qu'une rectification sur les termes, je trouve malgré tout que ton analyse est juste.

Answer (score 2):

[Synonyme](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/synonyme) : qui ont exactement le même sens.
[Quasi-synonyme](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/quasi-synonyme) : qui ont un sens proche.